# Help with the contrapositive of this statement

Tags: logic

I am taking a course on Distributed Algorithms but have no background on logic. I read about contraposition on wikipedia but I feel that the examples are too simple. This is the statement that I need help getting the contraposition of.

> **BEB1**. Validity: If pi and pj are correct, then every message broadcast
>   by pi is eventually delivered by pj

I understand that the contraposition of $P \implies Q$ is to flip the arrow and negate each element, becoming $\neg Q \implies \neg P$

As such, the contraposition of the statement above would be:

> If a message broadcast by pi is **not** eventually delivered by pj, then pi and pj are **not** correct

Is this correct ? I think I am wrong because I see 3 "variables" here. If $A, \text{then} \ B \implies C$

Comment: The first part is correct but for the second part you should say: one of $p_i$ or $p_j$ is incorrect.

Comment: No; the negation of "$p_i$ **and** $p_j$ are correct" is "either $p_i$ is **not** correct **or** $p_j$ is **not** correct".

Comment: thank you both ! may i know where I can read that the negation of and becomes or i.e. "$p_i$ and $p_j$ are correct" becomes "$p_i$ or $p_j$ is not correct" ? I feel like these are the important tiny bits that I am missing.

Comment: One more question: In my solution, should it be "If a message broadcast ..." or "If every message broadcast ..."

Comment: @kong Addressed in my answer: it is "If there is some message ...".  Remember that "not every thing is a bobbity" is "some thing is not a bobbity". $$\lnot\forall m~(Q(m)\to R(m))\equiv \exists m~(Q(m)\land\lnot R(m))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > **BEB1**. Validity: If pi and pj are correct, then every message broadcast by pi is eventually delivered by pj
>
> I understand that the contraposition of $P \implies Q$ is to flip the arrow and negate each element, becoming $\neg Q \implies \neg P$

You are mostly okay.    That understanding is correct.   You just have to take care with the negations.

Now here the sentence is $\forall p_i\forall p_j~((C(p_i)\land C(p_j) )~\to ~ \forall m~(B(m,p_i)\to D(m,p_j)))$ so the contraposition is $\forall p_i\forall p_j~(\exists m~(B(m,p_i)\land\lnot D(m,p_j))~\to~(\lnot C(p_i)\lor\lnot C(p_j)))$ .   More details below.

- Predicates used are: $C$ "is correct", $B$ "is broadcast by", and $D$ "is eventually delivered by".

> > If a message broadcast by pi is **not** eventually delivered by pj, then pi and pj are **not** correct
>
> Is this correct ? I think I am wrong because I see 3 "variables" here. If $A, \text{then} \ B \implies C$

*Nearly*

Yes, the conditional is nested. You are required to contraposition the parent conditional, which means negating the child conditional (and of course, also the child literal).   $P\to (Q\to R)$ maps to $\lnot(Q\to R)\to\lnot P$, and thence to $(Q\land\lnot R)\to\lnot P$.

In this case, $P$ is that both $p_i$ and $p_j$ are correct, $C(p_i)\land C(p_j)$, and the complement is that *at least one* of them is not correct.   $\lnot P$ is $\lnot C(p_i)\lor\lnot C(p_j)$.   Recall deMorgan's Rules.

Now what we shortened to $Q\to R$ is more correctly a universal quantified conditional: $\forall m~(B(m,p_i)\to D(m,p_j))$ -- *every* message, if it is broadcast by $p_i$, then it is eventually delivered by $p_j$.

The negation of this is an existential quantified conjunction: $\exists m~(B(m,p_i)\land\lnot D(m,p_j))$ -- there *is some* message which is broadcast by $p_i$, that is never delivered by $p_j$.   Recall the Duality of Universal and Existential Quantifiers.

Now since this applies to all $p_i,p_j$ we should have bound the entire conditional with universal quantifiers.   This will not be affected by the contraposition.   Thus obtaining the above expressions.

*Long story shortened:*

"If *there is* a message broadcast by pi *that is* is **not** eventually delivered by pj, then *at least one from* pi <s>and</s>*or* pj are **not** correct"  (emphasis is my corrections, emboldened is as you had it).