# Where do I place the negations when generating the contraposition of statements?

Tags: logic

I have a statement

> For any message m, if a correct process delivers m, then every correct
> process delivers m

What would its contrapositive be ?

> a) If every correct process **not** delivers m, then a correct process **not**
> delivers m
>
> b) If every **not**-correct process delivers m, then a
> **not**-correct process delivers m

Are they both correct ? If not, how do I know where I can place the negation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, both are wrong, the correct contraposition would be:

> If any correct process doesn't delivers m, no correct process delivers m.

---

Edit after your comment:

In your previous post, there was a **IF** [...] are correct.

Here, (at least in my opinion) we're only dealing with correct process. If the correctness of the process would be in doubt, it should have been phrased as:

> If a process is correct and delivers m, then every process, if correct, delivers m

And then the contraposition would be a bit harder. In fact, the second part of your implication would be an implication itself.

If your familiar with logical operators, let use the following notation:

- $\mathbb M$ is the set of all messages
- $\mathbb P$ is the set of all process
- $\mathbb {C(P)}$ is the set of all correct process
- $C(P)$ means "P is correct"
- $M(P)$ means "P delivers M"

So, your statement, as I get it can be written as:

$$\forall m \in \mathbb M, (\exists P \in \mathbb {C(P)}, M(P)) \implies (\forall P \in \mathbb {C(P)}, M(P))$$

While the second statement can be written as:
$$\forall m \in \mathbb M, (\exists P \in \mathbb P, C(P) \land M(P)) \implies (\forall P \in \mathbb P, C(P) \implies M(P))$$

You can check that the two statement are equivalent, the only difference is that in the first one, we don't care about any incorrect process.

Comment: Thank you but should I negate the correct as well ? (also asked below) Because in my previous post, the word correct was also negated in its contrapositive https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949801/help-with-the-contrapositive-of-this-statement?noredirect=1#comment6091326_2949801

Comment: @kong I edited my answer to deal with this problem

Comment: Thank you. I am also trying to approach it in an intuitive way. The statement I got is "If any correct process doesn't deliver m, all correct processes do not deliver m". The second half is equivalent to no correct processes deliver m. Is this okay ? Or should I have not reached at that statement at all ?

Comment: Yes, "no correct process delivers m" and "all correct processes do not deliver m" are indeed the same thing!

Comment: @kong You *may* negate the "is correct" predicate as well.  "If any correct process doesn't deliver $m$, ..." and "If any process is not correct or doesn't deliver $m$, ..." are equivalent .  $$C(p)\to\lnot D(p,m) ~\equiv~\neg C(p)\lor\lnot D(p,m)$$

Comment: thank you very much @F.Carette and Graham Kemp ! took me awhile to go through the notations